Data-Diff Python API : Numeric Precision does not work while comparing data between Oracle and Snowflake tables
I am using data_diff.diff_tables () (https://data-diff.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python-api.html) in order to compare the records between Source : Oracle and Target : Snowflake tables.
The code snippet is:
record_diff = diff_tables(source,target,key_columns,extra_columns,update_columns, bisection_factor,min_update,threaded,bisection_threshold,max_threadpool_size)

for sign, columns in record_diff:
print(sign,columns)

The Oracle table has Column A as -0.19 , Column B as 0.00
and Snowflake table has Column A as -0.19 and Column B as 0.00
But the results are
-,[-0,0]
+,[0,0]
What changes should be brought in order to capture the precision between records in the 2 tables and display only rows that have differences ?
I am using Windows Machine and data-diff version v0.11.0
#Oracle#Data-Diff#Snowflake#NumericPrecision
I have tried changing the defined datatypes within Oracle.py and Snowflake.py and the precision definition .
I have also executed via Cmd line
I tried switching the source and target
In all the scenarios, the precision values are not being captured.
